# Spring Boot can't intercept actuator access

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

In SpringBoot version 2.1.6 unable to intercept access actuator request 
 Now I have a global interceptor

```
@Component
public class ServiceFilter implements HandlerInterceptor {
//log4j
static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ServiceFilter.class);
private final RateLimiter limiter = RateLimiter.create(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2 + 1);
private final ThreadLocal<ExecuteRecordDto> executeRecord = new ThreadLocal<>();

public ServiceFilter() {

}

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    ExecuteRecordDto recordDto =  ExecuteRecordDto.bulider(request);
    executeRecord.set(recordDto);
    if (!limiter.tryAcquire()) {
        logger.warn("rate limiter ; json logger :  {}",CommonUtil.toJSONString(recordDto));
        response.getWriter().print(CommonUtil.toJSONString(ResultStatus.status(407, "rate limiter")));
        return false;
    }

    if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(request.getHeader("Authorization"))) {
        logger.warn("illegal request, json logger : {} ",CommonUtil.toJSONString(recordDto));
        response.getWriter().print(CommonUtil.toJSONString(ResultStatus.status(403, "Permission denied")));
        return false;
    }
    switch (TokenHandle.checkToken(request.getHeader("Authorization"))) {
        //正常放行token
        case 0:
            response.getWriter().print(CommonUtil.toJSONString(ResultStatus.status(407, "rate limiter")));
            return true;
        //token 过期
        case 1:
            response.getWriter().println(CommonUtil.toJSONString(ResultStatus.status(408, "Token expire")));
            break;
        //非法token
        case 2:
            logger.warn("illegal token, json logger : {} ",CommonUtil.toJSONString(recordDto));
            response.getWriter().print(CommonUtil.toJSONString(ResultStatus.status(409, "Illegal token ")));
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("server runtime exception");
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    ExecuteRecordDto recordDto = executeRecord.get();
    logger.info("json logger : {}",CommonUtil.toJSONString(recordDto));
    executeRecord.remove();
}
```

}

And make it work

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigFilter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
private final ServiceFilter filter;
@Autowired
public ConfigFilter(ServiceFilter filter){
    this.filter = filter;
}
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(filter).addPathPatterns("/**");
}
}
```

I requested my own api, get the effect I want
      [image: 1]

How can SpringBoot intercept a visit to actuator
      [image: 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actuator is using a different HandlerMapping (see: `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping`).

This Handlermapping will be chosen over your configured RequestHandlerMapping because of the order (-100 vs 0). You can see this in the `DispatcherServlet` precisely the method `HandlerExecutionChain getHandler(HttpServletRequest request)`.

In our projects we configure the access to the actuator endpoints with spring security so i'm not aware if there are any recommended ways to do it but:

The handler are chose by order so this a thing to consider, you can also try to manipulate the actuator `WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping`.

Like i said i'm not sure about the right solution, but i hope it points you in the right direction to find a proper solution.

regards, WiPu

Comment: also found this topic what might help you: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11234

Comment: would you please provide an example of how to manipulate WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping, I tried inheriting the class and calling extendInterceptor method but actuator endpoint is not visible