# Set interceptor only shutdown endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In Spring Boot version 2.2 I have an implementation of HandlerInterceptor and expose info, health, shutdown endpoints of Actuator.

I'd like to set that interceptor **only for the shutdown endpoint**, but not sure how to do it.

Already know that the code on the following page is useful for setting an interceptor for all endpoints.

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11234

```java
@Configuration
public class ActuatorConfig extends WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationInterceptor authenticationInterceptor;

  public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebAnnotationEndpointDiscoverer endpointDiscoverer,
                                                                       EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes,
                                                                       CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties,
                                                                       WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties) {
    WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping mapping = super.webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(
      endpointDiscoverer,
      endpointMediaTypes,
      corsProperties,
      webEndpointProperties);

    mapping.setInterceptors(authenticationInterceptor);

    return mapping;
  }
}
```

Also I checked this page

- [Spring Boot can't intercept actuator access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125304/spring-boot-cant-intercept-actuator-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments from spring team on github issue [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11234) suggest to create a filter for intercepting actuator endpoint.

You can create a servlet filter and add authentication logic.

Here is a example:

```
@Component
public class ActuatorFilter implements Filter {
    private final BasicPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new BasicPasswordEncryptor();
    private String encryptedPassword;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        try {
            File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:password.txt");
            try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(file)) {
                char[] chars = new char[(int) file.length()];
                reader.read(chars);
                encryptedPassword = new String(chars);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        String url = request.getRequestURI().toString();
        String rawPassword = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if(url.equals("/actuator/shutdown") && !passwordEncryptor.checkPassword(rawPassword,encryptedPassword)){
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print("Invalid password");
            out.flush();
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

In the above code i have used `jasypt` for encrypting password and matching it in filter.

You can use `new BasicPasswordEncryptor().encryptPassword(rawPassword);` to get a encrypted password and save it in either DB or file. In the above code i have saved the encrypted password in `password.txt` in `resources` folder

[image]